# Web scraping with R and selector gadget

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-parsing, rvest

I am trying to scrape data from [a website](http://blog.feedspot.com/video_game_news/) using R. I am using `rvest` in an  attempt to mimic [an example scraping the IMDB page for the Lego Movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/). The example advocates use of a tool called [Selector Gadget](http://selectorgadget.com) to help easily identify the `html_node` associated with the data you are seeking to pull.

I am ultimately interested in building a data frame that has the following schema/columns:
`rank`, `blog_name`, `facebook_fans`, `twitter_followers`, `alexa_rank`.

My code below. I was able to use Selector Gadget to correctly identity the html tag used in the Lego example. However, following the same process and same code structure as the Lego example, I get NAs (`...using firstNAs introduced by coercion[1] NA`
). My code is below:

```
data2_html = read_html("http://blog.feedspot.com/video_game_news/")
data2_html %>%
  html_node(".stats") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.numeric()
```

I have also experimented with: `html_node("html_node(".stats , .stats span"))`, which seems to work for the "Facebook fans" column since it reports 714 matches, however only returns 1 number is returned.

```
714 matches for .//*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' stats ')] | .//*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' stats ')]/descendant-or-self::*/span: using first{xml_node}
<td>
[1] <span>997,669</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you:

```
library(rvest)

d1 <- read_html("http://blog.feedspot.com/video_game_news/")

stats <- d1 %>%
    html_nodes(".stats") %>%
    html_text()

blogname <- d1%>%
    html_nodes(".tlink") %>%
    html_text()
```

Note that it is `html_nodes` (plural)

Result:

```
> head(blogname)
[1] "Kotaku - The Gamer's Guide" "IGN | Video Games"          "Xbox Wire"                  "Official PlayStation Blog" 
[5] "Nintendo Life "             "Game Informer" 

> head(stats,12)
 [1] "997,669"    "1,209,029"  "873"        "4,070,476"  "4,493,805"  "399"        "23,141,452" "10,210,993" "879"       
[10] "38,019,811" "12,059,607" "500"
```

`blogname` returns the list of blog names that is easy to manage. On the other hand the stats info comes out mixed. This is due to the way the `stats` class for Facebook and Twitter fans are indistinguishable from one another. In this case the output array has the information every three numbers, that is stats = c(fb, tw, alx, fb, tw, alx...). You should separate each vector from this one.

```
FBstats = stats[seq(1,length(stats),3)]

> head(stats[seq(1,length(stats),3)])
[1] "997,669"    "4,070,476"  "23,141,452" "38,019,811" "35,977"     "603,681"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `html_table` to extract the whole table with minimal work:

```r
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

# scrape html
h <- 'http://blog.feedspot.com/video_game_news/' %>% read_html()

game_blogs <- h %>% 
    html_node('table') %>%    # select enclosing table node
    html_table() %>%    # turn table into data.frame
    set_names(make.names) %>%    # make names syntactic
    mutate(Blog.Name = sub('\\s?\\+.*', '', Blog.Name)) %>%    # extract title from name info
    mutate_at(3:5, parse_number) %>%    # make numbers actually numbers
    tbl_df()    # for printing

game_blogs
#> # A tibble: 119 x 5
#>     Rank                  Blog.Name Facebook.Fans Twitter.Followers Alexa.Rank
#>    <int>                      <chr>         <dbl>             <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1     1 Kotaku - The Gamer's Guide        997669           1209029        873
#>  2     2          IGN | Video Games       4070476           4493805        399
#>  3     3                  Xbox Wire      23141452          10210993        879
#>  4     4  Official PlayStation Blog      38019811          12059607        500
#>  5     5              Nintendo Life         35977             95044      17727
#>  6     6              Game Informer        603681           1770812      10057
#>  7     7            Reddit | Gamers       1003705            430017         25
#>  8     8                    Polygon        623808            485827       1594
#>  9     9   Xbox Live's Major Nelson         65905            993481      23114
#> 10    10                      VG247        397798            202084       3960
#> # ... with 109 more rows
```

It's worth checking that everything is parsed like you want, but it should be usable at this point.

Comment: That looks really cool, but I'm unable to replicate your results. Error:  `game_blogs <- h %>% 
     html_node('table') %>%    # select enclosing table node
     html_table() %>%    # turn table into data.frame
     set_names(make.names)
Error: `x` and `nm` must be the same length`

Comment: Ah! Sorry, that's using the development version of `purrr::set_names`, which can take a function. You can install it from [Github](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/), or just use `set_names(make.names(names(.)))` which will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This uses `html_nodes` (plural) and `str_replace` to remove commas in numbers. Not sure if these are all the stats you need.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
data2_html = read_html("http://blog.feedspot.com/video_game_news/")
data2_html %>%
  html_nodes(".stats") %>%
  html_text() %>%
  str_replace_all(',', '') %>%
  as.numeric()
```